# what is considered "similar suitably sturdy materials" for Galder’s Tower

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

[Galder’s Tower](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/galders-tower) states

> You conjure a two-story tower made of stone, wood, or similar suitably sturdy materials.

What would qualify as "similar suitably sturdy materials"? The relevant definition of sturdy is "strong enough to withstand rough work or treatment." Assuming "similarly" sturdy, could the material be extremely hot stone? Would Mythril or diamond qualify under this?

Answer (score 3):

## This requires a DM's ruling

Pages 246/7 of the DMG offer guidelines for the armor class and hit points values of objects depending on their construction material and size:

| Material | AC |
| --- | --- |
| Cloth, paper, rope | 11 |
| Crystal, glass, ice | 13 |
| Wood, bone | 15 |
| Stone | 17 |
| Iron, steel | 19 |
| Mithral | 21 |
| Adamantine | 23 |

The materials of stone and wood explicitly mentioned in Galder's tower have suggested ACs of 17 and 15, respectively. Complicating matters is the fact that not all "stone" is the same. Sandstone would likely have a very different durability than granite, for (an extreme) example.

Are Mithril or diamond (which might fall under *crystal*) "similarly sturdy?" The bottom line is that the rules offer guidance but do not explicitly limit or allow a given material and so it falls to the DM to adjudicate this matter when it comes up at the table.